# Show that $x_{n+1} = \frac{2x_n}{\sqrt{1+2^{-n}x_n}+1}$ is monotone and bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I have the sequence
$$
x_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} \sqrt{1 + 2^{-n} x_n} - 1, 
\quad \mbox{for}~n\geq 1.
$$
We assume $x_0 > - 1$.

I need to prove that the sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n \geq 0}$ is bounded, monotone, and convergent, with limit
$$
\ln (x_0 + 1)
$$

The text gave the hint to rationalize, so I got to $x_{n+1} = \frac{2* x_n}{\sqrt{1+2^{-n}x_n}+1}$.  I ran some calculations and it is monotone decreacing, but I can't seem to get how to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @dezdichado I thought so, but if $x_0 = 0.5$, $\sqrt{1-0.5} + 1 \approx 0.707 + 1 \approx 1.707$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can write
$$
x_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} \Big(\sqrt{1 + 2^{-n} x_n} - 1\Big)
$$
Let us then define the auxiliary sequence $y_n = 2^{-n} x_n + 1$. We have
$$
y_{n+1} = \sqrt{y_n}.
$$
Therefore, $y_n = y_0^{1/(2^n)}$. Note $y_0 = x_0 + 1$.
Consequently,
$$
\lim x_n = \lim 2^n(y_n - 1)= \lim 2^n\Big[\exp\Big(\frac{1}{2^n} \log(1 + x_0)\Big) - 1\Big]
= \log( 1 + x_0), 
$$
by L'Hopital's rule.

That $x_n$ is bounded now follows trivially from the limit relation. As for the monotonicity, we start
by defining the function
$$
\psi(t) = t \Big[\exp\Big(\frac{c}{t}\Big)  - 1\Big], 
\quad \mbox{where}~c = \log(1+x_0).
$$
Then
$$
\psi'(t) = e^{c/t} \Big(1 - \frac{c}{t}\Big) - 1 \leq 0.
$$
where above we use the inequality $e^x \geq 1 + x$ for all real $x$.
This establishes that $\psi$ is a non increasing function. Now we note that
$$
x_n = \psi(2^n). 
$$
Then $x_{n+1} = \psi(2^{n+1}) \leq \psi(2^n) = x_n$. Note that this provides yet another proof of the boundedness of $x_n$, since
$$
\sup_n x_n = x_0, \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\inf_n x_n = \lim_n x_n = \log(1 + x_0).
$$

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand why can we assure that $y_{n+1} = \sqrt{y_n}$ ? Do the $-1$ and the $2^{-n}$ not change the recurrence relation?

Comment: @Rararat: Rewrite the recurrence relation as $1 + 2^{-(n+1)}x_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 + 2^{-n} x_n}$ ...

Comment: Thanks! And if I may ask, how do we get from $e^x \geq 1+x$ to $e^x * (1-x) -1 \leq 0$? I tried multiplying by $1-x$ both sides, using the fact that $x>0$ in this case, but I can't seem to get rid of the $x^2$

Comment: Apply the first inequality to $-x$. Does that help?